# Expand Categorical Column in a Time Series to Mulitple Per Second Count Columns

Tags: r, time-series

What is the best way to make the following transformation? There are two parts to this conversion. The first is to convert the speed to a per second mean. The second is to take the categorical column and transform that into multiple columns -- one column per categorical value where the value is the count of occurrences per second.  For example:

Input (xts A):

```
Time(PosixCT), Observed Letter, Speed
2011/01/11 12:12:01.100,A,1
2011/01/11 12:12:01.200,A,2
2011/01/11 12:12:01.400,B,3
2011/01/11 12:12:01.800,C,4
2011/01/11 12:12:02.200,D,2
2011/01/11 12:12:02.200,A,7
```

Output: (xts B)

```
Time, A_Per_Second, B_Per_Second, C_Per_Second, D_Per_Second, Aggregate_Speed
2011/01/11 12:12:01,2,1,1,0,2.5
2011/01/11 12:12:02,1,0,0,1,4.5
```

I am looking to do this in such a way that I don't need to know what all the categories are. Basically I am trying to collapsing the time to per second without loosing any of my categorical data and summarizing the numeric data as a per second mean.

Comment: can you replace your input data with the `dput(Input)` so others can have an exact copy of the data we should be working with?

Comment: Your output is missing a column.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: Thanks, fixed the missing column.

Comment: @chase: Andre has it in his answer, next time I will post that with my question.

Comment: Also, already learned from a previous question truncating the time to per second -- just use `align.time()`. But figured it is best to start with raw data so as not to skip steps when there might be better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the structure I'm using for `A`.  Note than the "numbers" are really character, since you can't mix types in a matrix.

```
A <- structure(c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"2", "7"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Observed_Letter", 
"Speed")), index = structure(c(1294769521.1, 1294769521.2, 1294769521.4, 
1294769521.8, 1294769522.2, 1294769522.2), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "",
class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

This function will clean up each of the categories.

```
clean <- function(x) {
  # construct xts object with only Speed and convert it to numeric
  out <- xts(as.numeric(x$Speed),index(x))
  # add column names
  colnames(out) <- paste(x$Observed_Letter[1],"_Per_Second",sep="")
  out  # return object
}
```

Here's the guts of what you need.  Note the need to explicitly state `split.default` since there's a `split` method for xts objects that splits by time.  You also don't *need* `align.time`, but it will round each period up to the whole second.  Otherwise your index will be the last actual value in the index for each second.

```
# split by Observed_Letter, apply clean() to each list element, and merge results
combA <- do.call(merge, lapply(split.default(A, A$Observed_Letter), clean))
alignA <- align.time(combA,1)
# get the last obs for each 1-second period (for period.apply)
EPalignA <- endpoints(combA, "seconds")
# count the number of non-NA observations by column for each 1-second period
counts <- period.apply(alignA, EPalignA, function(x) colSums(!is.na(x)))
# sum the non-NA observations for each column and 1-second period
values <- period.apply(alignA, EPalignA, colSums, na.rm=TRUE)
# calculate aggregate speed
B <- counts
B$Aggregate_Speed <- rowSums(values)/rowSums(counts)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't often use data in time series format (i.e. `xts`), so I provided a solution using data in `data.frame` format.

*(Note also that I have changed the column names of this data frame to single words to make it easier to work with. I post the structure of my data frame at the end of this question.)*

I make use of two packages:

1. `HMisc` for `trunc` methods for POSIXt classes
2. `plyr` for some magic to split, apply and combine data

The code:

```
A <- as.data.frame(A)

library(Hmisc)
A$Date <- trunc(A$Date, units="secs")
A

library(plyr)
ddply(A, .(Date, Observed), summarise, Speed=mean(Speed))
```

the results are in slightly different format than you specified, but it should be easy to reshape this into the wide format you asked for.

```
                 Date Observed Speed
1 2011-01-11 12:12:01        A   1.5
2 2011-01-11 12:12:01        B   3.0
3 2011-01-11 12:12:01        C   4.0
4 2011-01-11 12:12:02        A   7.0
5 2011-01-11 12:12:02        D   2.0
```

---

Here is the `dput` results of A:

```
A <- structure(list(Date = structure(list(sec = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2
), min = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), hour = c(12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), mday = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), 
    mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 
    111L, 111L, 111L), wday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    )), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", 
"wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = c("", 
"GMT", "BST")), Observed = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Speed = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L)), .Names = c("Date", "Observed", "Speed"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is interesting -- different what I asked for so trying to wrap my head around it. I think I would describe this as speed per second per observed. But what I really want, I think, is observed Per Second *and* Speed Per second. The reason is that taking the first second in my example, The As could impact the speed of B. Also, Speed won't be the only thing I will want to correlate against.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something like this: `ddply(A,.(Date),function(x){c(table(x$Observed),mean(x$Speed))})`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **zoo** solution.   First we read in the data splitting it on column 2.   Then we truncate the times to seconds and calculate the counts and sums.  Finally we put it all together.

```
Lines <- "Time(PosixCT), Observed Letter, Speed
2011/01/11 12:12:01.100,A,1
2011/01/11 12:12:01.200,A,2
2011/01/11 12:12:01.400,B,3
2011/01/11 12:12:01.800,C,4
2011/01/11 12:12:02.200,D,2
2011/01/11 12:12:02.200,A,7"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(textConnection(Lines), header = TRUE, sep = ",", split = 2, tz = "")

tt <- as.POSIXct(trunc(time(z), "sec"))
z.knt <- aggregate(z, tt, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
z.sum <- aggregate(z, tt, sum, na.rm = TRUE)

cbind(z.knt, Speed = rowSums(z.sum) / rowSums(z.knt))
```

The result looks like this:

```
                    A B C D Speed
2011-01-11 12:12:01 2 1 1 0   2.5
2011-01-11 12:12:02 1 0 0 1   4.5
```